# Remove a String from Json Object

Tags: java, json, avro

I am trying to convert an Avro Kafka Event to Json and need to manipulate The Avro Event by Removing Strings from this Event.

I am using GSON Library to manipulate the Json String Object but somehow its not removing the intended String.

```
JsonElement je = new Gson().fromJson(matchRequest, JsonElement.class);
        JsonObject jo = je.getAsJsonObject();
        jo.remove("com.XXX.XXXX");
        jo.remove("com.XXX.XXX");
        jo.remove("com.XXX.XXX");

        System.out.println("#################"+jo);

Json String I am Receiving as matchRequest is
{"interaction_id":"321","customer_id":"32","context_id":"123","work_id":"ewq","work_request_id":"213","task_type":"123","match_type":"wert","resource_list":{"com.xxx.xxxx":{"rank":1,"resource_data":{"com.xxx.xxxx":{"account_id":1,"source_name":"Mankind","channel_id":"voice"}}}},"service_list":{"com.xxx.xxxx":{"rank":5,"priority":1,"resource_count":"gvk","min_proficiency":"10","max_proficiency":"1","attributes":{"com.xxx.xxxx":{"category":"edw","value":"33232"}},"resource_offered":{"com.xxx.xxxx":{"agent_id":"rewq","account_id":"123","source_name":"wqe","resource_address":"ewq","source_address":"rewq","channel_id":"212","channel_provider":"wqe"}}}},"matching_state":"OFFERED"}
```

JSON Format

```
    "interaction_id": "321",
  "customer_id": "32",
  "context_id": "123",
  "work_id": "ewq",
  "work_request_id": "213",
  "task_type": "123",
  "match_type": "wert",
  "resource_list": {
    "com.XXXXXX": {
      "rank": 1,
      "resource_data": {
        "com.XXXX": {
          "account_id": 1,
          "source_name": "Mankind",
          "channel_id": "voice"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "service_list": {
    "com.XXXX": {
      "rank": 5,
      "priority": 1,
      "resource_count": "gvk",
      "min_proficiency": "10",
      "max_proficiency": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "com.XXXX": {
          "category": "edw",
          "value": "33232"
        }
      },
      "resource_offered": {
        "com.XXXX": {
          "agent_id": "rewq",
          "account_id": "123",
          "source_name": "wqe",
          "resource_address": "ewq",
          "source_address": "rewq",
          "channel_id": "212",
          "channel_provider": "wqe"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "matching_state": "OFFERED"
}
```

Comment: If you perform `jo.get("com.XXX.XXXX")`, do you get the intended content?

Comment: You should be performing the operation on the `resource_list` property, not on the root itself

Comment: You do not have a key `com.XXX.XXXX` in your `JSON` payload. Do you want to treat it as `JSONPath`? Maybe you should use [`JSONPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library. Try to clarify which nodes do you want to remove by providing result `JSON` after removing keys. Right now it is nor clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the documentation of the `remove()` method, it needs a key from the *JSON* object in parameter.

However, the *JSON* you are receiving does not contain "*com.xxx.xxxx*" as key, but some keys, like "*resource_list*", are linked to another *JSON* object containing "*com.xxx.xxxx*" as a key.

You may want to look recursively into the *JSON* object you receive to remove the intended *String*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform your operation over your array:

```
jo.getAsJsonObject("resource_list").remove("com.XXX.XXXX");
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This removes the Whole JSON "resource_list" not just the intended string.